# Header to a TableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qheaderview

I've been browsing everywhere and I just cannot find any information on how to create a certain type of header to a **TableView** in Qt Creator.

I want it to look similar to this:

[image: TableView]

Comment: do you have your custom Model???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer: there is no settings in the QTCreator that you can set to define the Header of a table view...

long answer: That is a TableView with custom model.
you need then to define a new Model that inherits the  QAbstractTableModel

and then in tne FooModel header override the headerData method

```
class FooModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

    //...
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const override;
    //... more methods may be here
```

then in the in cpp:

```
QVariant FooModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        switch (section)
        {
        case 0:
            return QString("Name");
        case 1:
            return QString("ID");
        case 2:
            return QString("HexID");
        // etc etc    
        }

    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

and finally in controller:

```
    myFooModel  = new FooModel(this);
    ui->myTableView->setModel(myFooModel);
```